About Ethereum Trading
Will this platform be merged with the Ethereum trading platform I invested in before? So can I get my Ether coins back that I invested before?

What do you mean by platform? There are several project that implemented some type of trading on the Ethereum blockchain. Ethereum is a blockchain, and anyone is able to write their own applications.
